# File is able to open but not returning anything?

Tags: c++, text-files, ifstream, getline

I'm having a problem trying to getline lines from a .txt file. I used a similar algorithm in another piece of code and document with seemingly no issues (= all lines were printed). However, when I try to the same thing using getline (As usual) i get my string line = "". My lines are not empty and I have a pre-test to check if the file opens, which it does. Below is a function from my program. Could anyone provide some help? Thanks!

I am trying to run case 'A'

```
  void Database::LoginMenu(string code)
  {
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Thank You for Login In, Would You Like To..." << endl;
    cout << "====================================================" << endl;
    cout << "A. View your registration information" << endl;
    cout << "B. Search for others" << endl;
    cout << "C. Search for Upcoming" << endl;
    cout << "D. Enter the Database" << endl;

    char choice, YN;

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Please choose an option: ";
    cin >> choice;

    switch(choice)
    {
    case 'A':
        {
            ifstream myfile("RegistrationInfo.txt");
            string line;
            if(myfile.is_open())
            {   
                while(!myfile.eof())
                {
                    getline(cin, line);

                    if(line[5] == ':')
                    {
                        line = line.substr(7, line.size());
                    }
                    if(line == code)
                    {
                        while(!line.empty())
                        {
                            cout << line << endl;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }   
            cout << "Would you like to return to the menu? (Y/N)";
            cin >> YN;      

            if(YN == 'Y')
            {
                LoginMenu(code);
            }

            myfile.close();
        }
        break;
    case 'B':
        {
            ifstream filein("RegistrationInfo.txt");
            string temp, YN, enteredInfo;
            int n = 0;

            cout << "Who do you wish to search for? :";
            cin >> enteredInfo;

            while(!filein.eof())
            {
                getline(cin, temp);
            }
        }
        break;
    case 'C': upcomingComps();
        break;
    case 'D': DatabaseMenu();
        break;
    }
  }
```

Here are a few lines form my txt file.

- CCode: abd50896
- Names: TomMullen NicoleLaBerge
- Compt: Rutgers DanceSport 2012
- Level: Newcomer
- Dance: Tango Waltz Quickstep Rumba ChaCha Jive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggest the call use myfile as the first argument, instead of cin -- `getline(myfile, line)` -- because cin represents stdin, which is not the file you opened.

Comment: wow, i didn't even realize that. Sorry for asking a such stupid question. Thank you so much for taking the time to look over it and finding my mistake! I wanted to click the accept button but I have to wait 8 mins. THANKS!

Comment: Haha, no problem. I've been there a few times myself.

Answer (score 0):

The most evident thing is that you open the file but you're reading from cin. Try changing cin into myfile.

Comment: Thank you! I've made the change and it worked :)